# how to use a directshow filter programmatically

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I am a newbie in development using Directshow.NET. I am trying to capture video using webcam. First I tried to build the graph using `GraphEdit` it's like.

Source cam--->Color Space converter--->Sample Grabber--->ASF writer

I know how to add source cam,sample grabber and ASF writer into graph programmatically in c#, but I don't get how to add `Color Space converter`. I tried adding by using `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID` and then `(IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(type)` it worked successfully, but is it safe to add filter by their CLSID because while adding sample grabber I used `ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;` and after this configured sample grabber with and then added to graph.

So is their any class or interface by which I can add `Color space converter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Color Space Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd387892) is standard filter existing in all versions of Windows. It is safe to instantiate it by its unique `CLSID` of `{1643E180-90F5-11CE-97D5-00AA0055595A}` (AKA `CLSID_Colour`).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Just a one question. How can we decide that which filter is standard filter and it's safe to instantiate by `CLSID`, is it like all the filters listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are standard filter  existing in all versions of Windows?

Comment: while recording video using graph mentioned in question, I used a custom `.prx` which I generated by `Windows Media Profile Editor`and configured into `IConfigAsfWriter`using `WMCreateProfileManager`. Mode is `CBR`, codec `Windows Media Video 9` and frame rate `15fps` with 759Kbps video bit rate, but still video looks so blurry when an object front of camera moves fast. If I increase video bit rate like upto 5Mbps then this blurriness is not coming but increasing bit rate results into large file size. Is this a normal behavior of asf writer?

Comment: Check documentation for specific filters to clarify the availability. Most of DirectShow core was developed in 199x and early 200x so well known filters are present in Win XP and on.

Comment: You should ask a separate question on WM ASF Writer: this is Q&A site (as opposed to forum/chat).